# How to enable Cisco AE6000 (usb wifi adapter) in VirtualBox Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, virtualbox

I would like to use Cisco AE6000 (usb wifi adapter) in VirtualBox Ubuntu or Kali.

I have tried the previous guides by googling. Currently, dmesg shows:

```
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------- –>RTUSBVenderReset fw version:0.1.00 build:7640 RTUSB_VendorRequest
> failed(-110), TxFlags=0x0, ReqType=OUT, Req=0x6,… … ERROR!!!
> NICLoadFirmware failed, Status[=0x00000001] !!! rt28xx init fail !!!
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> And I checked lsusb and iwconfig:
> *#lsusb Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13b1:003e Linksys Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
> Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux
> Foundation 1.1 root hub*
> #iwconfig ra0 Ralink STA eth1 no wireless extensions. lo no wireless extensions.
> #lshw -C network
> -network  DISABLED
>      description: Wireless interface
>      physical id: 1
>      logical id: ra0
>      capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
>      configuration: broadcast=yet driver=RALINK WLAN multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
> 
> =============================================================
```

Could any one help me ? is it possible to use Cisco Linksys AE6000 in VirtualBox?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you installed AE6000 driver?.. If not check with the vendor to provide the driver and then try to access.

Comment: This is mt7610u dongle. It support 802.11 ac and is new. The default driver in ubuntu, does not support this dongle. I built driver mt7610u_sta.ko followed http://hprath.com/2014/06/cisco-linksys-ae6000-ac580-media-tek-mt7610u-mt7630u-mt7650u-linux-x64-driver-patch/